# Regex for Date String in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex for both scenario. That have few number after decimal or no decimal places.

```
2015-06-29T14:07:25.963 
1985-02-17T00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the end of your regex, replace `.\d+$` by `(?:\.\d+)?$`

The dot `.` means any character and therefore needs to be escaped : `\.`

- `(?:` start of non capturing group
- `\.` literally a dot
- `\d+` followed by at least 1 digit
- `)?` end of the capturing group, that should appears 0 or 1 time (with `?`)

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/adwXv2/1)